# MySQL to Laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this query:

```
select concat(firstname, ' ', lastname), email
from users
    where id in(
    select user_id
        from company_user
            where company_id in (
            select id
                from companies
                where id in (
                    select company_id
                    from activities
                        where created_at between DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 8 DAY)
                            and DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 6 DAY)
                        )
                    )
                );
```

And I'd like to make it more "laravel-friendly".

I already did the models (and the relations on it) for each table:

Activity (who belongs to company)
Company (who has a N-to-N relationship with User)
User (who has a N-to-N relationship with Company)

I think it covers everything. Ask me any missing details.

Thanks.

Comment: Please take a look at the `whereHas` example, this should get you started, http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or with joins equal spencer7593 response:

```
User::select(DB::raw('CONCAT(users.firstname, ' ', users.lastname)'), 'users.email')
        ->join('company_user', 'company_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('companies', 'companies.id', '=', 'company_user.company_id')
        ->join('activities', 'activities.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [
            DB::raw('CURDATE() - INTERVAL 8 DAY'),
            DB::raw('CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY')
        ])
        ->groupBy('users.id')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could start with making the query more MySQL friendly, by using simple join operations rather than all the `IN (subquery)` constructs.

For example:

```
    SELECT CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname)
         , u.email
      FROM users u
      JOIN company_user cu
        ON cu.user_id = u.id
      JOIN companies c
        ON c.id = cu.company_id
      JOIN activities a
        ON a.company_id = c.id
     WHERE a.created_at BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 8 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
     GROUP BY u.id
```

Answer (score 1):

For custom and complex Queries, I recommend to use the "DB:select()" function,
for performance reasons.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#running-queries

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this code, but believe it to be this way ;)

```
User::select(DB::raw('concat(firstname, ' ', lastname)'), 'email')
    ->whereIn('users.id', function ($query) {
            $query->select('company_user.user_id')
                  ->from('company_user')
                  ->whereIn('company_id', function ($query2) {
                        $query2->select('companies.id')
                              ->from('companies')
                              ->whereIn('companies.id', function ($query3) {
                                    $query3->select('activities.company_id')
                                           ->from('activities')
                                           ->whereBetween('created_at', [
                                                DB::raw('DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 8 DAY)'),
                                                DB::raw('DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 6 DAY)')
                                            ]);

                              });
                  });
        })->get();
```